# Javascript "mirroring" a number

Tags: javascript

Let's say I've:

```
var firstNumber = 0;
var lastNumber = 160;
```

If, on a event, 160 is selected, I want a function that returns 0, if 120 is selected, it should return 40, if 80 is selected, it should return 80 (half between first and last number) and move on, until if 0 is selected, it have to return 160.

How is possible to do so?

Comment: uh, what event? who selects what? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If 160 is selected, shouldn't it return 0? And if it's really 1, shouldn't it return 41 if 120 is selected?

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a homework, is it?

Comment: I don't think the example numbers are consistent.

Comment: @melpomene you're right, I've edited the question

Comment: Yeah, that's called subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event just do `let desiredNumber = lastNumber - selectedNumber` and it will give you the number you are looking for.

It is not so much  ***'mirroring'***, more of a subtraction to me.

Comment: One could consider it a mirroring around the center of a number line

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```js
const mirror = (min, max, num) => Math.abs(num - max - min)

console.log(mirror(0, 160, 160))
console.log(mirror(0, 160, 120))
console.log(mirror(0, 160, 80))
console.log(mirror(0, 160, 0))
```

Althought I don't see how this can be called "mirroring".

Comment: On a number line it could

Comment: I was just working on a line, that's why i got confused

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function:

```js
var firstNumber = 1;
var lastNumber = 160;

var mirroning = [];
var index = 0;
var mirrorValue = lastNumber;

var test = function() {

  for (var i = firstNumber; i <= lastNumber; i++) {
    var obj = {
      "value": i,
      "mirror": mirrorValue
    };
    mirroning[index] = obj;
    mirrorValue--;
    index++;
  }

  return mirroning;
};
console.log(test())
```

In this case when the value is 1 the mirror is 160 and when it is 160 the mirror is 1 but when the value is 80 the mirror is 81